# Firebase is updating wrong children

Tags: android, firebase

I wish to update on the `users` nodes as well as the `presentUsersByPhoneNumber` node within my database.

However, when using the code outlined below:

```
            // Create in users table:
            final Firebase usersRef = myFeastFirebaseNewUser.child("users");

            Map<String, String> newUserAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            newUserAttributes.put("username", mUsername.getText().toString());
            newUserAttributes.put("password", mPassword.getText().toString());
            newUserAttributes.put("phoneNumber", mPhoneNum.getText().toString());
            newUserAttributes.put("email", mEmail.getText().toString());

            Map<String, Object> createNewUser = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            createNewUser.put(result.get("uid").toString(), newUserAttributes);
            usersRef.updateChildren(createNewUser);

            // Create in presentUsersByPhoneNumber:
            final Firebase userByPhoneNumber = myFeastFirebasePhoneSearch.child("presentUsersByPhoneNumber");

            Map<String, String> newUserID = new HashMap<String, String>();
            newUserID.put("uid", result.get("uid").toString());

            Map<String, Object> createNewUsesPhoneRef = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            createNewUser.put("1" + mPhoneNum.getText().toString(), newUserID);
            userByPhoneNumber.updateChildren(createNewUsesPhoneRef);
```

The result is:

[image]

What I wish to do is set the node `presentUsersByPhoneNumber` with the content in red upon save.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is in the Android code. In updating the phone number reference, I am using the object on line: `createNewUser.put("1" + mPhoneNum.getText().toString(), newUserID);` which is incorrect, cannot believe I missed it...

Comment: Thanks for the update. But next time, include the actual JSON and not a screenshot of the JSON. StackOverflow <> Twitter.

Comment: Let's first either close this one or self-answer, as it is not likely to be of any use to anyone. Aside from that: you don't need to tag me on unrelated questions. I either get to yours or I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The Android code should have been:

```
            Map<String, Object> createNewUsesPhoneRef = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            createNewUsesPhoneRef.put("1" + mPhoneNum.getText().toString(), newUserID);
            userByPhoneNumber.updateChildren(createNewUsesPhoneRef);
```

not a reference to `createNewUser`